# How to serve static files from S3 using CloudFront

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I have a CloudFront distribution in front of 2 origins:

- S3
- API Gateway (Lambda)

I want all the static files to be served from S3, and the rest from API Gateway.

FYI I'm trying to reproduce a classic PHP setup with static files served by Nginx and the rest served by PHP through PHP-FPM.

How can I achieve that?

What I am currently doing is this:

[image]

It works, but it clearly sucks because I have to add all the static file extensions manually. Is there a way to match all static files? Or to check if a file exists in S3 and serve it from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1.  Let the default pattern be the bucket, and create a cache behavior with the path pattern for the API, like `/api/*`.  Possibly not practical here.

Option 2.  Match the dot before the extension for sending requests for files to S3, as `/*.??` `/*.???` etc.  The `?` placeholder matches  [*exactly* one character](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern) and without a `*` at the end, there must be a dot within that many characters of the end of the path.

Option 3.  Match a prefix like `/assets/*` and send all of these requests to the bucket.  Store all your objects with `assets/` at the beginning of the object key.

Comment: Thank you, that's too bad there is no better option. I have ended up using the `*.*` pattern to match file names (those will be served by S3).